# Update MongoDB structure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

Locally I have a MongoDB which is working fine. On a server (the live version) is is working fine also, but locally I have added some collections and specifications to existing collections.
The site files have been updated to the server, but I don't know now how to update the structure. Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Database: MongoDB, Server: NodeJS on Amazon AWS

(I'm new with MongoDB, nodeJS and Amazon AWS. I am later embarked on this project and the other developer is on vacation)

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/core/import-export/

Comment: I don't want to ex and import the data but only want to update the structure of the collections.

Comment: Give us a concrete example of one change you want to make. There are simply methods, and in the "worst case" you have most of the full power of Javascript at your disposal to update whatever you want.

Comment: What do you mean by _specifications_? I can't seem to find any documentation about those, and I don't want to mislead if they're something I just don't know about!

Comment: I think if you just need update the structure of the collections, you just need update the schema in code, the new structure will apply for all new data . Same with collections, it will auto create on db when have record save to that . If you still want to work with your db, you can use **MongoChef**, it has UI that will help you a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the indistinctness. There was nothing wrong with the database files but there was an error during the merge of some files, which has a result that the save function was not complete en didn't save the new specs on the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably talk to someone who understands more about your exact situation than I, but you may not need to do anything. MongoDB automatically creates collections as they are used (see the first couple sentences of the [description](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) of the `db.createCollection` method). So, since you don't care about the local data, you probably don't need to do anything to create the remote collections. They will just appear as soon as data is inserted into them.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by *specifications*. If you mean queries: as far as I can tell, they shouldn't cause problems even if they refer to collections that don't exist on the server. When I tested a query locally on a non-existent collection, it simply returns no results.

You might find this FAQ page for MongoDB helpful as well:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#how-do-i-create-a-database-and-a-collection